# inequality geometry problem with a triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

Sorry if line $m$ is not centered completely however I wanted to stress that it doesn't need to be a right angle for a triangle like this to be true.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true. In general, we have
$$m\lt\frac{a+b}{2}.$$

**Proof** : By [parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law), we have
$$a^2+b^2=2\left(m^2+\left(\frac c2\right)^2\right)\Rightarrow 2m=\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}.$$
Hence, we have
$$\begin{align}2m-(a+b)&=\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}-(a+b)\\&=\frac{(\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}-(a+b))(\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}+(a+b))}{\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}+(a+b)}\\&=\frac{(2a^2+2b^2-c^2)-(a+b)^2}{\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}+(a+b)}\\&=\frac{(a-b-c)(a-b+c)}{\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}+(a+b)}\lt 0\end{align}$$
because we have
$$b+c\gt a\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ a+c\gt b.$$
Hence, we have
$$2m-(a+b)\lt 0\iff m\lt\frac{a+b}{2}.$$

Comment: You use the triangle inequality on the original triangle; it might be simpler to use the triangle inequality on the triangle with sides $a,b,2m$ (which is half of the parallelogram you use in your invocation of the parallelogram law).

Answer (score 0):

Find value of C

from Left-side 
$C=2\sqrt{a^2-m^2}$

From right side
$m^2=\sqrt{b^2+a^2}/(2)$

You might continue the solution from these...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complex answer:

Suppose $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $|1+z|+|1-z| \ge \sqrt{|1+z|^2 + |1-z|^2} = \sqrt{2+ |z|^2} \ge 2$. Furthermore, we have equality **iff** $z=0$.

Now suppose $z \neq 0$ and let $w \in \mathbb{C}$, then $|z+w|+|z-w| = |z| (|1+{ w \over z}| + |1-{w \over z}|) \ge 2 |z|$.

[image]

We see that $a = |z-w|, b = |z+w|$ and $m= |z|$, hence $a+b \ge 2m$. Since $m>0, w \neq 0$, we have $a+b > 2m$.